# How to find an element in AJAX callback with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, find

Whenever I try to find say, the body of the returned page from AJAX, it returns null. Here's my JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: 'testpagec.php', 
            type: 'GET',

            success: function(data) {
                var test = $(data).find('body');
                alert(test.html());

            }
        });
    return false;
});
});
```

This looks perfect on paper but it's not working as intended. Any ideas on fixing this? Thanks.

Comment: Use console.log instead of alert, and log data to check what's getting returned.

Comment: What're you doing with this data? A document should not have two `body` elements, and I'm pretty sure they're not allowed to be nested... =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What works for me is this

```
 var $data = $('<div>').html( data ); 
 $data.find('body'); // this works now
```

The reason the above works is because `body` was not an ancestor hence `find` didn't work, giving the data a root level element will ensure find works. You can also use `.filter`.

```
$data.filter('body');
```

Comment: The other option (same result) is to set the `dataType` setting in your ajax call to `html`